# C++ Sort unable to resolve identifier begin and end?(Keeping arrays together)

Tags: c++, sorting, netbeans, bubble-sort

I'm trying to sort my array *pairs* by int, but my sort is saying 'unable to resolve identifier' to pairs.begin(), pairs.end(), and compare_pairs_second(). I cannot figure out why but i'm probably doing something wrong?
Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iomanip>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
using namespace std;
main()
{
string name[10];//declaring an array name
int number[10];//declaring an array number

cout << "Please input 10 names \n";//output
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){//for statement
    cin >> name[i];//inputting names in the array names
}
cout << "Please input their corresponding numbers \n";//output
for(int x = 0; x < 10; x++){
    cin >> number[x];//inputting numbers
}//end for
int i = 0;//redeclaring i to be 0
int x = 0;//redeclaring x to be 0
for(int l = 0; l < 10; l++)//for statement
{
    cout << name[i] << ": " << number[x] << "\n";
    i++;//adding 1 to i so outputs all of array name
    x++;//adding 1 to x so outputs all of array number
}//end for
pair<string, int> pairs[10];
int i = 0;
int x = 0;
for(int z = 0; z < 10; z++)
{
    pairs[z] = make_pair(name[i], number[x]);
    i++;
    x++;
}
std::sort(pairs.begin(), pairs.end(), compare_pairs_second<std::less>());
int i = 0;
int x = 0;
for(int z = 0; z < 10; z++)
{
    name[i] = pairs[z].first;
    number[x] = pairs[z].second;
    i++;
    x++;
}
string search = "";
cout << "Enter a name to search for";
cin >> search;
size_t found = pairs.find(search);
if(found!=string::npos)
    cout << search << pairs;
} //end main
```

UPDATE/EDIT:
I got my sort to work...to an extent. I deleted the line of code that was giving me errors, and it now sorts my number array, which is half of what I wanted. But now how do I keep the names with their respective numbers without using my pairs variable that I had prior to this fix?
Ex 
array number[5]={5, 2, 9, 11, 27}; 
array name[5]={"Steve", "John", "Bob", "Larry", "Patric"};
Output after sorting:
John: 2 Steve: 5 Bob: 9 Larry: 11 Patric: 27

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iomanip>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
using namespace std;

main()
{
const int size = 10;
string name[10];//declaring an array name
int number[10];//declaring an array number

cout << "Please input 10 names \n";//output
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){//for statement
    cin >> name[i];//inputting names in the array names
}
cout << "Please input their corresponding numbers \n";//output
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    cin >> number[i];//inputting numbers
}//end for
sort(number,number+size);

int i;
int j;
int min;
int counter = 0;

for(i = 0; i < counter; i++)
{
    min = i;
    for(j = i+1; j < counter; j++)
    {
        if(name[j] < name[min])
        {
            string tempString = name[i];
            name[i] = name[j];
            name[j] = tempString;

            int tempInt = number[i];
            number[i] = number[j];
            number[j] = tempInt;
        }
    }
}
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    cout << name[i] << ": " << number[i] << "\n";
};
} //end main
```

Current output sorts numbers but does not keep names with them.

Comment: You can try using `std::array<std::pair<std::string, int>, 10> pairs;`

Answer (score 1):

`pairs` is raw array, not a STL container; you can't invoke method on it like `pairs.begin()` and `pairs.end()`.

Since C++11 you could use [std::begin()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin) and [std::end()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/end), which are overloaded for supporting raw arrays. e.g.

```
std::sort(std::begin(pairs), std::end(pairs), compare_pairs_second<std::less>());
```

Comment: I changed my code to see if your solution would work, it is still giving me that unable to resolve identifier to begin and end, but the one for compare went away.

Comment: @Griffinflame Does the compiler support C++11?

Comment: Yes I just checked, it does.

Comment: @Griffinflame Where's the definition of `compare_pairs_second`? I can't find it in your code.

Comment: @Griffinflame Better to post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).